# How do I get the possible "self attributes" of a Python class?

Tags: python, class

For example how can I define the properties of a class object in Python? How can I define what happens when I add two objects? Or multiply them? Or divide them? Or print them? Or if I call one with a number of arguments?

I see things like `__mul__` and `__add__` but what are these called and what are the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called operator overloading.

```
class Human(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __add__(self, other):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.name, other.name)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.name * len(other.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

bob = Human('Bob')
sam = Human('Sam')

print sam + bob # calls __add__
print sam * bob # calls __mul__

print bob # calls __str__
```

Comment: So why not __ add instead?

Comment: What do you mean? These are special methods derived from the base object class.

Comment: I see online various examples of when people use methods that only have one half of those underscores present (__ add instead of __ add __ )

Comment: That's just a convention for private methods, which don't really exist in Python. `__add` won't have any significance.

Comment: Thanks, was really confused by that

Answer (score 1):

`__mul__` and `__add__` are methods you call within your class that affect how you multiply and add two instances of your class, respectively. These [special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) are used to control how instances operate.

Comment: What is the difference between "__ add" and "__ add __"? (spaces added to prevent bold)

Comment: The first will not affect how you add the instances, it will just operate as any other method will.

Comment: Is there some difference with the second?

Comment: Yes, the second **will**, upon completion, contain the code necessary to add the two instances.

Answer (score 0):

To know what special name methods that are a part of the object, type `dir(object_name)`

For example, to see what methods are a part of strings:

```
>>> dir(str)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__',
'__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__'
, '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_e
x__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__',
 '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'enco
de', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower',
 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind'
, 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip',
'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

Just be careful with these special methods.

Instead of this:

```
>>> "a".__add__("b")
'ab'
```

Do this:

```
>>> "a" + "b"
'ab'
```

Here's an example of how to do matrix addition, with your own custom matrix class.

```
class Matrix():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __add__(self, b):
        i = j = 0
        c = []
        while i < len(self.a):
            c.append([])
            while j < len(self.a[0]):
                c[i].append(self.a[i][j] + b[i][j])
                j += 1
            j = 0
            i+= 1

        return Matrix(c)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.a[i]

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join([str(i) for i in self.a])

a = Matrix( [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] )
b = Matrix( [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] )

print a
print "+"
print b
print "="
print a + b
```

Comment: I think I will need __ add __ though to overload operators

Comment: If you're trying to implement your own `__add__` for a custom class, then that's fine. Every time you call A + B then it will call your `__add__` method.

Comment: I added an example with matrices if you're still interested.